# Making Transparent Image Layer not effect top layer image

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have an indesign image, that has a Transparency effect placed upon in via `Objects->Effects`. However, I would like the image that is on the top most layer above the transparent layer to not be effected by the Opacity of the bottom image. Is there a way to do this? I have tried the Knockout and Isolate options shown in the attached image to no success.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand.

I assume you are wanting the logo to be 100% opacity while the photo behind it is 60% opacity.

In order to do that you need the logo image **placed as a *separate* object**. InDesign does **not** allow you to pick and choose object layers for its effects. The InDesign effects apply to the entire object. They essentially alter the frame, not the contents within the frame.

If the photo/logo is a layered Photoshop document, you can adjust opacity in Photoshop, then replace the linked image rather than using InDesign for opacity.

Comment: Ah! I thought the logo was a subject object, but it wasn't!